# jquery pull data from html attribute on click

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes

I'm trying to create a simple way to pull information from a custom HTML attribute when I have multiple buttons to click with the same 'id'.

I'd like to know if I can pass the 'url' attribute value from the specific button I press.  Right now, it always just grabs the first one...

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(":input[id='alarm']").click(function() {
        alert($("input[url]").attr("url"));
    });
});
</script>

<table id='alarms'>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>CaseID</th>
    <th>Alarm</th>

    <tr>
        <td width="50">2040</td>
        <td width="180">TEST-111110-123-R4</td>
        <td><input id="alarm" type="button" value="Cancel" url="../silencealarm.php?id=2040"></td>
    </tr>
        <td width="50">2042</td>
        <td width="180">TEST-111110-123-R6</td>
        <td><input id="alarm" type="button" value="Cancel" url="../silencealarm.php?id=2042"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `this` (*don't use duplicate id's though*)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(":input[id='alarm']").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("url"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah!  Thank you all.  Just one of those dirt simple things that wizz past your head.  Can I tag this '#brainfart'? :)

Answer (score 2):

While using the custom HTML attribute prefix with `data-*` and inside your handler this refres to the element itself so just access it with `$(this).data("url")`

```
 $(":input[id='alarm']").click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("url"));
    });
```

Do not use duplicate id, It makes your HTML invalid and your handler will be attached only to the first instance, SO change it to class instead.

### Markup

```
<tr>
        <td width="50">2040</td>
        <td width="180">TEST-111110-123-R4</td>
        <td><input class="alarm" type="button" value="Cancel" data-url="../silencealarm.php?id=2040"></td>
    </tr>
        <td width="50">2042</td>
        <td width="180">TEST-111110-123-R6</td>
        <td><input class="alarm" type="button" value="Cancel" data-url="../silencealarm.php?id=2042"></td>
    </tr>
```

#### Script

```
$(":input.alarm").click(function() {
        alert($(this).data("url"));
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6guUw/)

Answer (score 0):

just simple change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(":input[id='alarm']").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("url")); //or
        alert($(this).prop("url"));
    });
});
```